# Sketching the derivative a graph with asymptotes.

Tags: derivatives

I have to sketch the derivative of a particular graph (see attached image), however, it seems my answer is wrong, but I do not understand why. If anyone could help explain why I’m wrong, that would be great!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The axes aren't labeled or numbered, other than that I can't see anything wrong with it...
Since it's decreasing everywhere its derivative will always be negative, and since it tends to a constant as x goes to infinity the derivative should tend to zero, so your solution checks out.

Comment: That’s what I was thinking. It may be a mistake in the actual solution

Comment: I'm curious now though, did you find out what happened?

Comment: I asked my teacher and he also thinks its a mistake.